# How to implement creation of simple quizzes in python-markdown?

Tags: markdown, pelican, python-markdown

I recently found tech.io's playgrounds. I'm absolutely amazed with their quiz Markdown extension.
I have a blog created with Pelican, and this type of quizzes would be a perfect addition.

For those unfamiliar with tech.io's quiz syntax...

```markdown
?[How do you say 1 in spanish?]
-[ ] eins
-[x] uno
-[ ] unu
```

What type of processor should I use? Any suggestion about how should it look like?

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate use of Pelican. Pelican is a static site generator. It does not seem suitable or intended for interactive sites such as taking a quiz.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question though.

Comment: I am sorry about a late answer. I ended up creating a custom block inside an existing Markdown extension library, and it suits my needs. Here's the repo to check it, if somebody needs a similar thing: https://github.com/vlajna95/markdown-customblocks